# The script does not save changes to the system file

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, shell, debian

The python script should change the hostname of the machine to the one given to it. But after the reboot, the file remains empty. However, if I open the file before rebooting using nano and save it manually, then after rebooting the hostname will remain what the script specified. I didn't find a similar problem on the Internet, please help.
Moreover, it does not work not only with system files, the rest of the files are saved. Maybe I don't understand something about rights. I run the script from root(#python3 script.sh).
My OS: debian 10

```
import os

hostname = input("hostname: ")
os.system("rm /etc/hostname")
file2 = open('/etc/hostname','w')
file2.write(hostname)
print("successfully")

reb = input("reboot?(y)")
if reb =="y": os.system("reboot")
else: print(":(")
```

Comment: Aside: use `os.unlink('filename')` or `os.remove('filename')` instead of `os.system('rm filename')` -- it's not just more efficient, it gives you better error messages and avoids security problems. But there's generally not a good reason to remove the old file before writing the new one in the first place.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to be sure your new content is written, you should _close_ the file after you write to it, and maybe even call `os.fsync()` on the file and directory that contains it to make sure it makes it all the way to disk.

Comment: Anyhow -- if it were truly a permissions issue specific to system files, you'd see an exception thrown. (There _is_ potential for there to be other moving parts -- config automation and the like -- rewriting the file on boot so the changes, even when successfully changed, don't "stick" -- but before trying to dig into that, follow the advice in the linked duplicate to make sure you _are_ successfully saving the new content).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks a lot, I'll take into account the advice about closing the file. I added the command `file2.close()` after record the file and it solved my problem.